# Sync UID/GID on SLES 12.1 with winbind connected to AD

Tags: samba, sles, active-directory

I have multiple SLES 12.1 Servers which I joined into the AD Domain via `net ads join -u <OU_MANAGER> osName='SLES' osVer='12.1' createcomputer="<OU1>/<OU2>/Servers`. It is important to note that I only have an OU Manager Account for OU2 and do not manage the AD itself. 
The join finishes successful, but there is the typical `DNS_GSS_ERROR` which I can't fix since according to the [Troubleshooting](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Troubleshooting_Samba_Domain_Members#DNS_Update_failed:_ERROR_DNS_GSS_ERROR) you need to be the AD admin.
Nonetheless I joined the domain and when activating the option to allow login for domain users via YaST (somehow it does not work when I do the nsswitch.conf, pam and sshd settings myself) I can logon with the domain users.

The problem is I want to synchronize the UID/GID of the users, since they run decentral Java Applications and they are dependant on that.

My current `/etc/samba/smb.conf` looks as follows:

```
[global]
    workgroup = XXXX
    realm = XXXX.YYYY.NET

    security = ADS
    kerberos method = secrets and keytab

    template homedir = /home/%D/%U
    template shell = /bin/bash

    winbind refresh tickets = yes
    idmap gid = 19500-19999
    idmap uid = 19500-19999
    usershare allow guests = No
    winbind offline logon = yes
```

When I now try to change the idmap to the following

```
[global]
    workgroup = XXXX
    realm = XXXX.YYYY.NET

    security = ADS
    kerberos method = secrets and keytab

    template homedir = /home/%D/%U
    template shell = /bin/bash

    winbind refresh tickets = yes
    #idmap gid = 19500-19999
    #idmap uid = 19500-19999
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    idmap config * : range = 1000-5000
    idmap config XXXX : backend = rid
    idmap config XXXX : range = 19500-19999
    usershare allow guests = No
    winbind offline logon = yes
```

and then run `smbcontrol all reload-config` followed by `systemctl restart smb winbind` I won't be able to log on with domain users anymore.
I receive the following error:

```
Kinit for <Servername>$@XXXX.YYYY.NET to access cifs/<domain controller>.xxxx.yyyy.net@XXXX.YYYY.NET failed: Preauthentication failed
```

But I can use `net ads kerberos kinit -u <OU Manager>` and `kinit -u <OU Manager>` so I don't see the issue?

Has anybody else any more ideas or am I missing anything?
Is it the fault of the AD Admins or mine?